# Apply cascade delete in one to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

If I have two required foreign keys in class and these keys compose this class primary key and we have another class contain list of this class how to implement cascade delete in this case entity framework code first

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public JobType JobType { get; set; }
    public double JobBudget { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsAccepted { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public List<Proposal> Proposals { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Client { get; set; }
}

public class Proposal
{
    public string FreelancerId { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public bool IsAccepted { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser Freelancer { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}

public PostConfigurations()
{
        Property(p => p.ClientName)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.JobType)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.JobBudget)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.CreationDate)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.JobDescription)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        HasOptional(p => p.Proposals)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true)
}

public class ProposalConfigurations : EntityTypeConfiguration<Proposal>
{
    public ProposalConfigurations()
    {
        HasKey(p => new { p.FreelancerId, p.PostId });

        Property(p => p.FreelancerId)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.PostId)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

I tried many things, but failed, can you please help?

Comment: What failed / how did it fail?

Comment: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Proposals_dbo.Posts_PostId' on table 'Proposals' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: There are soooo many questions about this error. Please look for them and see what it means and how to prevent it.